# Stacking a number of columns into one column in python

Tags: python, pandas, stack, edge-list

I have a pandas dataframe of 100 rows x 7 columns like this:

[image]

Values in column `source` are connected to the values in the other columns. For example, `a` is connected to `contact_1, contact_2... contact_5`.
In the same way, `b` is connected to `contact_6, contact_7 .... and contact_10`.

**I want to stack these columns into two columns only (i.e. source and destination), to help me build a graph using edgelist format.**

The expected output data format is:

[image]

I tried `df.stack()` but did not get the desired result, I got the following:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate, there are [21 questions on pandas wide_to_long](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+wide_to_long+is%3Aq). Please identify the dupe target then close this. There are also tons of questions on [tag:edge-list].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html). This should do:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='destination_', i=['source'], j='number')
```

The column `destination_` will have the info you're looking for.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'source': ['a', 'b'],
 'destination_1': ['contact_1', 'contact_6'],
 'destination_2': ['contact_2', 'contact_7']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='destination_', i=['source'], j='number')
```

Output:

```
              destination_
source number             
a      1         contact_1
b      1         contact_6
a      2         contact_2
b      2         contact_7
```

Comment: It is giving me an error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'. I am using Anaconda 2.4

Comment: Is there something different in your data with respect to your example? Using the data you provided, the answer works

Comment: I applied the example that you provided above. Still gives me the same error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
is it due to Anaconda version? i am using 2.4

Comment: Should be because of that. Do you have any way to install Python 3+ ?

Comment: I am trying this now

Comment: It worked fine when using Anaconda 3.5. So, the version was the reason why it didn't work the first time. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I'm not sure what changed between Python 2 and Python3 that makes this code unusable in the former, though

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `pandas.DataFrame.melt`, which rearranges the dataframe so that one column is now an identifier variable and the rest value variables. You can read more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt).

You can apply `DataFrame.melt` to your data as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={
    "source": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "destination_1": ["contact_1", "contact_6", "contact_11"],
    "destination_2": ["contact_2", "contact_7", "contact_12"],
    ...
})

output_df = df.melt(id_vars=["source"])
# value_vars automatically inferred to be the remaining columns.
```

This will output a DataFrame object which looks something like

```
   source       variable       value
0       a  destination_1   contact_1
1       b  destination_1   contact_6
2       c  destination_1  contact_11
3       a  destination_2   contact_2
4       b  destination_2   contact_7
5       c  destination_2  contact_12
.       .              .           .
.       .              .           .
.       .              .           .
```

You can sort by the `source` column with `output_df.sort_values(by=["source"])`. If you want, you can then drop the `variable` column and rename the `value` column to `destination`. You can also reset the index after sorting with `output_df.reset_index(drop=True)`.